# how to make $http requests from angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I have a problem with my code, i don't seem to know how and where to place the code to make an $http request to a local server.

api.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Place = mongoose.model('Place');

module.exports = function(app){
app.get('/api/place', function(req, res){
    Place.find(function (err, places){
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json(places);
    });
});
};


router.route('/place')

.post(function(req, res) {

var place = new Place();

place.name = req.body.name;
place.address = req.body.address;
place.created_at = req.body.created_at;

place.save(function(err){
    if (err){
        return res.status(500).send(err);
    }
    return res.json({message: 'Place added', place});
});

})

.get(function(req, res){

Place.find(function(err, place){
    if(err){
        return res.send(500, err);
    }
    return res.status(200).send({place: place});
});


});

router.route('/place/:id')

.get(function(req, res){
Place.findById(req.params.id, function(err, place){
    if(err)
        return res.send(err);
    res.json(place);
});
})

.put(function(req, res){
Place.findById(req.params.id, function(err, place){
    if(err)
        res.send(err);
    place.name = req.body.name;
    place.address = req.body.address;
    place.created_at = req.body.created_at;

    place.save(function(err, place){
        if(err)
            res.send(err);
        res.json(place);


    });
});
})

.delete(function(req, res){
Place.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function(err){
    if(err)
        res.send(err);
    res.json({message: 'Place removed!!!!!'});
});

});

module.exports = router;
```

script.js

```
// script.js

// create the module and name it scotchApp
var app = angular.module('scotchApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);

// configure our routes
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider

       // route for the home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'home.html',
            controller  : 'mainController'
        })

        // route for the about page
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl : 'about.html',
            controller  : 'aboutController'
        })

        // route for the contact page
        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl : 'contact.html',
            controller  : 'contactController'
        })

        //route for the contact page
        .when('/register', {
            templateUrl : 'register.html',
            controller : 'registerController'
        })

        //route for the login page
        .when('/sign-in', {
            templateUrl : 'sign-in.html',
            controller : 'signinController'
    });
});

app.factory('placeService', function($resource){
    return $resource('/api/place');
});
// create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
app.controller('mainController', function($scope, $rootScope, $http) {
    // create a message to display in our view

          /* $scope.place = placeService.query();
           $scope.newPlace = {name: '', address: '', created_at: ''};

           $scope.place = function(){
              $scope.newPlace.created_by = $rootScope.current_user;
              $scope.newPlace.created_at = Date.now();
              placeService.save($scope.newPlace, function(){ $scope.place =      placeService.query();
              $scope.newPlace = {name: '', address: '', created_at: ''};
               }); */   
     $http.get('/api/place').success(function(data){
        $scope.place = req.data.place;
        console.log(data);


    });
});


 app.controller('placesController', function($scope, $http) {
    var url = 'http://localhost:8080/api/places';
    $http.get(url).success(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
});

app.controller('aboutController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Look! I am an about page.';
});

app.controller('contactController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Contact us! JK. This is just a demo.';
}); 

app.controller('registerController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Join us! JK. This is just a demo.';
}); 

app.controller('signinController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Login. This is just a demo.';
});
```

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/myproject');
require('./model/models')
var index = require('./routes/index');
var api = require('./routes/api');


var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/index', index);
app.use('/api', api);


var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
  error: err
});
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
   message: err.message,
   error: {}
 });
});

app.listen(port);               

// shoutout to the user                     
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);
module.exports = app;
```

Am in beginner at programming, so please correct my little mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

create a constant.js file(it will keep all constants and API URL). Create a service/Factory. Service/factory will serve the data by API call. Keep all your http calls inside that(inside service). you can have separate Service for each controller or can have single service for all controllers (depends on how clean code you want). from controller: call service method to get the data. service will return promise. using that promise you can get data in controller.
$http call return promise (it is inbuilt in Angular).

Example below

```
    (function (module) {
                var appConstants = {

                    empApi: {
                        employee: 'your url to call(http://something.com/sfsadf)',
                    },

                };
                module.constant('appConstants', appConstants);

            }(angular.module("app")));


        (function (module) {

            module.factory("dataService", ["$http", "appConstants", 
function ($http, appConstants) {

                this.getEmp = function () {
                    return $http.get(appConstants.empApi.employee);
                };

                return this;
            }]);

        }(angular.module("app")));


    (function (module) {

        module.controller("empController", ["dataService", function (dataService) {    
            var _this = this;

            dataService.getEmp ().then(function(result){
                _this.data = result.data;
            });

        }]);

    }(angular.module("app")));
```

Comment: so this means i require a service or a factory that will serve the data, if i separate each service from the controller, where would i require them? in app.js or api.js @RajRj

Comment: U can create as many services as u want. Inject them to your controller whenever u need them. Once service is available to you controller you can call the methods defined inside "service" which will return "promise".  I have shared the example where "dataService" is my SERVICE which has getEmp() method. Inject "dataService" in your controller and call the getEmp()  method (Like: var then = dataService.getEmp () ).
Now u have PROMISE "THEN" using which you can get data. Follow the example for more clarity. you can create a folder called "services" where you will write all your service JS files